# Configuration start caroufredsel

Tags: jquery, configuration, caroufredsel

I've been searching forums but can not find the solution and I do not get to see that happen to me " carouFredSel " .

I need to always start with a certain image and seen in the official website there is a way to configure it : start

I've tried but I can not implement .

In HTML, I have the carousel:

```
           

<div class="list_carouselhome">
    <div id="foo">`enter code here`
        <span><img class= "first" src="img/interior.jpg" /></span>
        <span><img src="img/interior2.png" /></span>
        <span><img src="img/interior3.png" /></span>
        <span><img src="img/interior4.png" /></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

And in a another file "script.js" , I have the function:

```
$(function() {
    //  Scrolled by user interaction
    $('#foo').carouFredSel({
        auto: true,
        prev: '#prev1',
        next: '#next1',
        items: {
            start: "#foo .first"
        },
        auto: {
            pauseOnHover: 'resume',
            timeoutDuration: '50000'
        }
    }, {
        transition: true
    });
});
```

I've put a class = "first" to the first image I want you to load and the function are indicated as well : start: "#foo .first"

Could you help me?. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You have a space in Yuor HTML:

```
<span><img class="first" src="img/interior.jpg" /></span>
```

Just try to write:

```
  items: {
            start: "#first"
        },
```

where the HTML:

```
<div class="list_carouselhome">
    <div id="foo">`enter code here`
        <span><img id="first" src="img/interior.jpg" /></span>
        <span><img src="img/interior2.png" /></span>
        <span><img src="img/interior3.png" /></span>
        <span><img src="img/interior4.png" /></span>
    </div>
</div>
```